# Can't edit hosts file on macOS 13.5 (sudo not working)

Tags: macos, terminal, filesystem, hosts

I don't have permission to edit the `hosts` file, even if I use `sudo` and turn off SIP.

I use `sudo vim /etc/hosts` to open the `hosts` file. After entering `:wq!`, it shows:

```
"hosts" E212: Can't open file for writing
```

like I am not using `sudo`.

I also tried using `sudo nano /etc/hosts` and it said:

```
[ Cannot open file for writing: Operation not permitted ]
```

Then I try `sudo chflags nouchg /etc/hosts`, but it makes no change.

BTW, inside the Finder, there is a lock in the lower-left corner of the `hosts` file. I try to change the lock status in **Get info** but the lock icon is not clickable.

Answer (score 1):

After I enter `sysctl kern.securelevel` and `sudo chflags noschg /etc/hosts`, the `schg` flag of the `hosts` file has magically disappeared. Now it is editable!